# Quoting Dialogue from a Book

Tags: quotations, quotation-marks

So, I'm writing a paper on Fight Club by Chuck Palahniuk and I have several quotes either with dialogue or quotes in them (depending on the way you look at it) but I don't know if I've correctly quoted them.  What tripping me up is when to use the single quotation marks. Here's an example of what I mean...

> The Narrator and Marla bond because they both go to the support groups to feel alive but they both don’t have anything; “Marla doesn’t have testicular cancer. Marla doesn’t have tuberculosis. She isn’t dying. Okay in the brainy brain-food philosophy way, we’re all dying, but Marla isn’t dying in the way Chloe was dying. So, Marla how do you like them apples? … ‘You’re not dying either,’ Marla says, ‘you tell on me and I’ll tell on you.’”

Comment: @medica That rule seems to apply to short quotes that are put inline in the sentence. Tim Romano's answer seems to be more appropriate when quoting long passages like this.

Comment: You'd do (almost) exactly what you did above -- indent the text.  If you have the capability you might also change the font somehow.

Answer (score 1):

The conventional way to quote a *passage* from a work of fiction is to present the passage in a slightly smaller font than your own text; the passage is indented (shifted to the right) and it has a larger right margin than your own text too; and you honor its line-breaks and its punctuation. You don't place quotation marks around the narrator's words, and you don't substitute your own punctuation for the author's.  For example, if the author doesn't put quotation marks around dialog, neither do you.